# View list of objects which has any of it's standard button overridden by LC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, metadata-api, metadata, object, lightning-quickaction

I have an existing application, which has around 100 objects. My requirement is to check all the objects which have any of their standard button/quick overridden with a lightning component.

Doing this manually will be a time consuming process. Is there any way to do this using any app exchange app or metadata API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize your IDE (VS Code) to do this pretty quickly.

First, pull all your custom objects.

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject`

Next, you can search through the *object-meta.xml* files to find the relevant [ActionOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm). If you're overriding a standard button with a lightning component, you'll find something like the following in the metadata file

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>New</actionName>
    <content>LightningComponentName</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>LightningComponent</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

The key here is that there's `<content>` and `<type>` which refers to the name of the component that is being used in the override of the standard button and what type it is (in your case, you care about lightning component).

> Set this field if type is set to flexipage, lightningcomponent,
>   scontrol, or visualforce. It refers to the name of the Lightning page,
>   Lightning component, s-control, or Visualforce page to use as the
>   override.

This wouldn't exist if you're not overriding. You can do a search for this
`<content>` or `<type>` in your object directory.

1. Shift+ALT+F will open up the search panel. Or simply right click on "objects" folder and select the option to "Find in Folder"
2. Select the /objects directory
3. Type `<content>` in the search or `<type>LightningComponent</type>`

[image]

Be aware this will return all overrides on the object (including overrides with Lightning Page assignments) if just using `<content>`.

You can click on "Open in Editor" to see a nice list of the references per object.

[image]